# VBA Excel Password will always accept last item in string (using Case)

Tags: vba, excel

This has been solved. Posted the proper code myself below. Someone shared and then removed it for an unknown reason so I duplicated it below. I am not allowed to answer my own question for 2 days however so I apologize if you came here to help. I am all set but our process is listed below.

I am currently having an issue with my code shown below. When I complete this action, it will only unlock whomever's name is listed last in the MyPassword section. For example, no matter *what* I type, Laura's sheet is ALWAYS executed and will make the sheet visible. I tested this by switching Chris to the third slot in just the MyPassword section and it then would make only his sheet visible even if a wrong password was entered.

Objective: They click a button and a box appears for a password. They enter their password and see only their sheet as listed in the row "Case is".

What happens: No matter what is entered, whomever's name is listed last in this section:

```
Dim MyPassword As String
    MyPassword = "Amanda"
    MyPassword = "Chris"
    MyPassword = "Laura"
    If InputBox("Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password") <> MyPassword Then
```

Then they will have their page show. In this case it is Laura.

I am self taught. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Pass()


Dim MyPassword As String
    MyPassword = "Amanda"
    MyPassword = "Chris"
    MyPassword = "Laura"
    If InputBox("Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password") <> MyPassword Then

Select Case MyPassword
   Case Is = "Amanda"
      Sheets("Amanda").Visible = True
   Case Is = "Chris"
      Sheets("Chris").Visible = True
   Case Is = "Laura"
      Sheets("Laura").Visible = True
   Case ""
      MsgBox "Password can not be empty."
   Case Else
      MsgBox "Wrong password. Please contact the Compliance Department if you do not have a password."
End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Note: Please stop telling me this is not the way to do this because there are back doors around this where they can still see xlVeryHidden sheets. The audience is not proficient in excel.

Comment: You are overwriting your password with MyPassword = "Amanda"
    MyPassword = "Chris"
    MyPassword = "Laura"

Comment: So the only password is actually Laura. You will need perhaps a pass word array that you check the given password against.

Comment: That's because the  assignation operator (`=`) overwrite the value of `MyPassword`. So when you are at the `Select Case` the value will always be "Laura". Try stepping through that code with the debugger and inspect the value of `MyPassword` at every line and you should understand.

Comment: Oh! This is great information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted a corrected code and removed it for some reason. Here is the proper and working way they offered. (Please note the passwords are just placeholders. The passwords we use will not be like this.

```
Sub Pass()

Dim MyPassword As String

MyPassword = InputBox("Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password")

Select Case MyPassword
   Case "Amanda"
      Sheets("Amanda").Visible = True
   Case "Chris"
      Sheets("Chris").Visible = True
   Case "Laura"
      Sheets("Laura").Visible = True
   Case ""
      MsgBox "Password can not be empty."
   Case Else
      MsgBox "Wrong password. Please contact the Outcomes Department if you do not have a password."
End Select

End Sub
```